# Removing styles from a partial HTML page

Tags: html, css

[image: HID]

I'm working on a wesbite that has fixed styles and partial html pages. 
I'm on one of the partials and I don't want the header in that specific page.

On inspect element, I see that the header is declared as '.header .utility'.
How do I reset .header. utility to make it show no header?

Comment: Sounds like you could just call it as `.header{ display:none !important;}`.

If you can show us code, or perhaps a link to your page we would be able to assist you further. :)

Comment: That worked!! thanks.. Please answer the question so I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you used display none property it will be always in DOM,you can see it.
If you are using angular JS use ng-if, if condition is false it will not be in DOM

Comment: Thanks. How do I use the ng-if?

Comment: In your controller for the required page make $scope,showHeader=true;

Comment: @Arun I think it's $scope.showHeader=true; not $scope,showHeader=true;

Comment: Thank you Arun and Ishimdar :)